# Find separated maxima in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

Given a numpy ndarray, how to find all peaks, but each peak should be at least some fixed distance away from the others. The reason is that often there is one peak, and then the next many peaks are just the neighboring points of the first peak, so they are not any "new" peaks.

I am sure there must be better implementations, and that is what I am asking for.
To illustrate what I would like, here is an example of something I just threw together (I have edited to improved the example, and added an image at the end):

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp
import scipy.ndimage
def findpeaks(objective, maxpeaks=10, gap=0):
    obj = objective.copy()
    peaks = np.zeros([maxpeaks, 2], dtype=int)
    for n in range(maxpeaks):
        peak = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(obj, axis=None), obj.shape)
        peaks[n,:] = peak
        obj[np.maximum(0,peak[0]-gap):np.minimum(40,peak[0]+gap),
            np.maximum(0,peak[1]-gap):np.minimum(40,peak[1]+gap)] = 0
    return peaks

np.random.seed(12345)
x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, [40,40])
x = sp.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(x, [3,3], mode='constant')

peaks = findpeaks(x, 10, 5)
print(peaks.T)
print(x[peaks[:,0],peaks[:,1]])
print(np.array(np.unravel_index(x.flatten().argsort()[-10:][::-1],x.shape)))
for p in peaks:
    x[p[0]-1:p[0]+2,p[1]]=0
    x[p[0],p[1]-1:p[1]+2]=0
plt.imshow(x, cmap='gray')
```

The output is

```py
[[27 11 26 24  5 16 25 16 13 31]
 [11 14 16  5 13 34 21 14  8 16]]
[0.55472915 0.54961331 0.53829221 0.5353206  0.53512158 0.52064241
 0.51729225 0.51557288 0.51025817 0.50846277]
[[27 27 26 28 27 28 26 27 26 11]
 [11 12 11 11 10 12 12 13 10 14]]
```

[image: The x array and its maxima]

It takes a random `x` array, and applies a gaussian filter just to make it smooth. This smoothness is why once you find one maximum, the others will usually be its neighbors.

The `findpeaks` method finds separated peaks. The locations of those peaks is the first two lines in the output.

The middle two lines are the values of the 10 maxima.

The last two lines are the locations of the largest points using a cutoff. As is visible, you just get a number of points which are contiguous.

Comment: You could try to implement a gradient ascent.

Comment: Why do gradient ascent? I can just find the exact maximum. It is the second, separated maximum that is the issue.

Comment: You are trying to find peaks in a n-dimensional array, I can't see other way you could do that efficiently without looking at gradients. Gradients will help you see how your curve is behaving, this way you won't get these 'contiguous peaks'.

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.signal.find_peaks` is exactly what you're looking for :-) 
from [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html#scipy.signal.find_peaks), the `distance` keyword does exactly that - requires the peak to be higher than all points up to a distance of `distance` from it.

Comment: Unfortunately only one-dimensional.